# Sqoop changes Date to Long when ingested data is saved as avrodata

Tags: oracle, sqoop

Using Oracle to ingest the data to HDFS as avrodata using SQOOP. The date/timestamp column fields are changed to long so the value is getting altered.

Example :
28-MAR-18 12.42.06.328000 PM changes to 1523401161454.

Any insights on the issue.

Comment: Did you give a try with what is suggested in this link?https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/39141/sqoop-changing-datatype-from-datetime-to-varchar.html.

Comment: @kaushik nayak Thank you,--map-column-java worked fine for me.